# Receiving *** caught segfault ***, 'memory not mapped' and mangled results after passing values from R to C

Tags: c, r, linux, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement a simple integration of R with C. Initially it's simple: I want to pass values from R to a C function built into a .o shared library via `.C` or `.Call` function. The C function should simply print the values passed in via `printf`.

Here's my `.Call` method:

```
.Call("test", as.integer(5), as.character("A"), as.character("string_test"))
```

And my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int integer, char character, char **str) {
        printf("Integer: %i\nChar: %c\nString: %s\n", integer, character, *str);
}
```

But when I call the C function from R via console (RStudio crashes) with `gdb` enabled, I receive:

```
Integer: 1466480376  
Char: �  
Float: -100407552.000000  
String:   
***caught segfault ***  
address 0x20000090, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("test", as.integer(5), as.character("A"), as.character("string_test"))
```

As if it were not enough, as we can see the values passed in are printed very strangely.

Details of what I did, step by step:

I built the `.o` shared library with `gcc`:

```
gcc -shared -o func_teste.o -fPIC func_teste.c
```

And prepared it for dynamic loading in R environment:

```
$ R CMD SHLIB func_teste.o 
gcc -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c func_teste.c -o func_teste.o
gcc -m64 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -o func_teste.so func_teste.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
```

And finally, inside R console, i ran:

```
>dyn.load('func_teste.o')
>.Call("test", as.integer(5), as.character("A"), as.character("string_test"))
```

Does anyone have idea why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like GNU (or the R Team) provides outstanding documentation. Also see [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html). More generally, see [The R Manuals](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html). I'm kind of envious of how good the docs are.

Comment: OP appears to confuse `.C()` calling convention with `.Call()` usage.

Answer (score 2):

R offers two main functions for interfacing from C code (and hence C++ code, or any other language able to use a C interface):
- `.C()` is the older interface using `int*`, `double*`, ... and alike
- `.Call()` is the newer, more powerful interface using `SEXP` objects

Now, `.Call()` looks more complicated but it is *so much more powerful* as well as safer.  There is near universal consensus that `.C()` should no longer be used (see various discussions on the r-devel list and other places).

The main downside with `.Call()` is that you need to learn how to pack and unpack your values.  Or ... you cheat and let Rcpp do it for you.  So with that, here is one-line solution of the OP's example:

```
> library(Rcpp)
> cppFunction("void mytest(int i, char c, std::string str) { printf(\"Integer: %i  Char: %c  String: %s\\n\", i, c, str.c_str()); }")
> mytest(42L, 'Q', "a boat")
Integer: 42  Char: Q  String: a boat
>
```

I made the `char*` a string.  Note that `cppFunction()` requires escaping of strings, you may want to look into `sourceCpp()` and packages for real work.  The Rcpp documentation has details.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `as.character` on `"string_test"`.
Read more here: http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=1067

Comment: The link is dead.